# Why do I get divergence convergence testing in Python code error and crumb error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, quantitative-finance, back-testing

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint
# just set the seed for the random number generator
np.random.seed(107)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Generate a fake security X and model it’s daily returns by drawing from a normal distribution. Then perform a cumulative sum to get the value of X on each day.

```
# Generate daily returns
Xreturns = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100) 
# sum them and shift all the prices up
X = pd.Series(np.cumsum(
Xreturns), name='X') + 50
X.plot(figsize=(15,7))
plt.show()
```

Generate Y which has deep economic link to X, so price of Y should vary pretty similarly as X.

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
Y = X + 5 + noise
Y.name = 'Y'
pd.concat([X, Y], axis=1).plot(figsize=(15,7))
plt.show()
```

Plot the ratio between the two:

```
(Y/X).plot(figsize=(15,7)) 
plt.axhline((Y/X).mean(), color='red', linestyle='--') 
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(['Price Ratio', 'Mean'])
plt.show()

# compute the p-value of the cointegration test
# will inform us as to whether the ratio between the 2 timeseries is stationary
# around its mean
score, pvalue, _ = coint(X,Y)
print (pvalue)

ret1 = np.random.normal(1, 1, 100)
ret2 = np.random.normal(2, 1, 100)

s1 = pd.Series( np.cumsum(ret1), name='X')
s2 = pd.Series( np.cumsum(ret2), name='Y')

pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1 ).plot(figsize=(15,7))
plt.show()
print 'Correlation: ' + str(X_diverging.corr(Y_diverging))
score, pvalue, _ = coint(X_diverging,Y_diverging)
print 'Cointegration test p-value: ' + str(pvalue)
```

Error Message:
File "", line 9
print 'Correlation: ' + str(X_diverging.corr(Y_diverging))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
Y2 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 1, 800), name='Y2') + 20
Y3 = Y2.copy()

Y3[0:100] = 30
Y3[100:200] = 10
Y3[200:300] = 30
Y3[300:400] = 10
Y3[400:500] = 30
Y3[500:600] = 10
Y3[600:700] = 30
Y3[700:800] = 10
Y2.plot(figsize=(15,7))
Y3.plot()
plt.ylim([0, 40])
plt.show()
# correlation is nearly zero
print 'Correlation: ' + str(Y2.corr(Y3))
score, pvalue, _ = coint(Y2,Y3)
print 'Cointegration test p-value: ' + str(pvalue)
```

Error message:File "", line 14
print 'Correlation: ' + str(Y2.corr(Y3))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
def find_cointegrated_pairs(data):
n = data.shape[1]
score_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
pvalue_matrix = np.ones((n, n))
keys = data.keys()
pairs = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        S1 = data[keys[i]]
        S2 = data[keys[j]]
        result = coint(S1, S2)
        score = result[0]
        pvalue = result[1]
        score_matrix[i, j] = score
        pvalue_matrix[i, j] = pvalue
        if pvalue < 0.02:
            pairs.append((keys[i], keys[j]))
 return score_matrix, pvalue_matrix, pairs
```

pip install auquan-toolbox and execute following code snippet:

```
 from backtester.dataSource.yahoo_data_source import YahooStockDataSource
 from datetime import datetime
 startDateStr = '2007/12/01'
 endDateStr = '2017/12/01'
 cachedFolderName = 'yahooData/'
 dataSetId = 'testPairsTrading'
 instrumentIds = ['SPY','AAPL','ADBE','SYMC','EBAY','MSFT','QCOM',
             'HPQ','JNPR','AMD','IBM']
 ds = YahooStockDataSource(cachedFolderName=cachedFolderName,
                        dataSetId=dataSetId,
                        instrumentIds=instrumentIds,
                        startDateStr=startDateStr,
                        endDateStr=endDateStr,
                        event='history')
 data = ds.getBookDataByFeature()['Adj Close']
 data.head(3)
```

Error message:File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtester\dataSource\data_source_utils.py", line 25, in getCookieForYahoo
return cookie, crumb  # return a tuple of crumb and cookie

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'crumb' referenced before assignment

[Complete article with code can be found here](https://medium.com/auquan/pairs-trading-data-science-7dbedafcfe5a).

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On errors regarding the print function you miss parentheses.

Eg. this error:

> Error Message: File "", line 9 print 'Correlation: ' + str(X_diverging.corr(Y_diverging)) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

is caused by the line 9:

```
print 'Correlation: ' + str(X_diverging.corr(Y_diverging))
```

which should be:

```
print('Correlation: ' + str(X_diverging.corr(Y_diverging)))
```